# Can't move elements in css divs

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, banner

For some reason I have a parent div called banner which contains a number of child divs, however in my css styles sheet I can't seem to move any elements especially the "CRAFT412" logo image to my desired position within the banner. I've tried using left/right/top/bottom to move these elements but nothing seems to budge them. If anyone could help me here I'd appreciative it.

Here is my HTML for a page on my site

```
<!--TOP BANNER SECTION-->

    <div id="banner">

        <div id="logo"> 
            <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Logo.png" width="500" height="281" alt="CRAFT412">
        </div>

        <div id="ip_box"></div>

        <div id="ip_text">
            <p>SERVER IP<P/>
            <p>craft412.serveminecraft.net<P/>
        </div>

        <div id="teamspeak_box"></div>

        <div id="teamspeak_box_2"></div>

        <div id="teamspeak_text">
            <p>TEAMSPEAK<P/>
        </div>


        <div id="teamspeak_image"> 
            <a href="ts3server://craft412.serveminecraft.net:9987">
                <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Box - Teamspeak.png" alt="TEAMSPEAK">
            </a>
        </div>                                    
    </div>
```

Also here is my CSS for the same divs

```
/*CSS FOR ALL PAGES*/

/*BODY/WRAPPER SECTION*/

body {
    background:#EEEEEE;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 2px 0px;
    border: 1.5px solid #E0E0E0;
    color: #E0E0E0;
}

/*TOP BANNER SECTION*/

#banner { height:100px; }

#logo {}

#ip_box {
    width:200px;
    height:43px;
    background:#212121;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;}

#ip_text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#teamspeak_box {
    width:159px;
    height:43px;
    background:#212121;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;
}

#teamspeak_box_2 {
    width:43px;
    height:43px;
    background:#313131;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

#teamspeak_text { color: white; }          

#teamspeak_image {}
```

Comment: Are you trying to position them absolutely within the banner div? If so, make sure to set `position: relative;` within the `#banner` segment. Then you can use `position: absolute;` and `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`, etc. in the child items

Comment: Well I tried that but doing so instantly disables the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent div a property :

```
Position:relative;
```

Also give the property to child div:

```
Position:absolute;
```

Now you can change the places of child div inside the "BANNER" div. by using `TOP` , `BOTTOM`, `RIGHT`, `LEFT`

Comment: That instantly disables the navigation bar, and removes a red line I added on top of the nav bar.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y9sfrwg2/ I can see the problem but I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: just wait for a while let me see.

Comment: Not a problem, take your time.

Comment: Can you give me a sketch of it ? I mean I want to see the placement of box. I will make you the whole header :)

Comment: http://gyazo.com/1b871c4fb6ac0ab1912845719cfe71d4 For now I've just positioned the craft412 logo image, i've made the red line appear again, and basically it seems as though the logo overhangs the nav bar so I can't press the buttons to navigate as the logo is for some reason is blocking it.

Comment: Remove the IP_TEXT dive and place the whole text of IP_TEXT in IP_BOX.
Go to CSS line #28, give property: Color : white;

Comment: Also give an other CSS #ip_text p{ margin:0px important}

Comment: I did that nothing seemed to change the nav bar still seems blocked. I have this now which is better on the ip text and box. http://gyazo.com/e393d38343090bcb6a57d3f7553d056b

Comment: This is what it looked like http://gyazo.com/5e75ebc1c8914f7f125597b4d262a9d1 with a smaller wrapper width, this is how I'd like it basically, with the red line on top of the nav bar, like this site: http://linustechtips.com/main/

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jbg08wjmtj72u92/New%20folder.rar?dl=0 Download your header from here !